# Change the default icon for QSystemTrayIcon notifications

Tags: c++, macos, qt, notifications, icons

I am recently developing a Qt-based client for [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/), and I have found myself struck with a small problem: I want to show notifications each time you get a notification in your mobile device (mirrored notifications, in the API), which works perfectly using `showMessage()` from `QSystemTrayIcon`. However, the icon on the notification, on OS X, is the default "paper and rulers" icon for apps that don't have an icon, although I have set the application icon file according to the instructions for OS X stated [in the official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/appicon.html).

I know it is not possible to set a custom icon for such notifications, which would be desirable (the Pushbullet API transmits the icon of the notification on your Android device as well, and the official browser plugins show it accordingly), but the application's icon should be possible, as per all other OS X apps (a Qt example would be TeamSpeak 3).

**EDIT - FIXED:** After looking in the Notifications section of the System Preferences, I noticed that my app had two entries, one with the icon and one without it. By simply disabling the one without the icon, it's now working.

Comment: Have you tried `qApp->setWindowIcon()`? Also, how do you call `showMessage`? It has `MessageIcon` parameter, you know.

Comment: `MessageIcon` seems to have no effect on OS X, it simply sets the icon on Windows and perhaps some distros of Linux (warning is the yellow triangle with exclamation mark, information is the blue circle with an i, etc.). `qApp->setWindowIcon()` puts a small version of the icon to the left of the window's title, but doesn't change the notifications' icon.

Comment: Did you set the icon in the .pro file like that link describes?

Comment: After looking in the Notifications section of the System Preferences, I noticed that my app had two entries, one with the icon and one without it. By simply disabling the one without the icon, it's now working.